# Behavior of Akka file mailbox queue

Tags: akka

We are trying to use Akka file based durable mailbox in our application. Few queries on how the message queue is maintained and persisted.

During tests, I observed that the entries in the queue which resides under "_mb" folder gets cleared at some intervals. I observed that when the queue size was above 20Mb and when the actor was no longer receiving any message the queue got cleared.

In the actual production use case, this actor will be continuously bombarded with messages. I tried to simulate this and i saw the queue size was increasing beyond 150Mb.

Just wanted to know the limits and the algorithm behind purging/clearing these entries.

Suppose the queue file size under "_mb" folder is say 1Gb. If I restart my application will akka try to load a lot of these messages into memory. I am curious to know about this behavior. If there is an eviction policy for these entries, how can i control this.

Comment: I want to know the significance of this configuration setting        # maximum size of a queue before it drops into read-behind mode.
max-memory-size = 128 MiB